# Can I save my running containers when upgrading from `docker` to `docker-ce`?

Tags: docker, centos

I've a CentOS 7 box with the default Docker 1.12 package (`docker`) running about a dozen containers. I want to upgrade to the latest Docker package (`docker-ce`) provided in their repository, according to these [instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/centos/#install-docker-ce).

However, I have to uninstall the `docker` package, first. Will this trash my running containers? If so, is there anyway to avoid that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually a functionality starting at docker 1.12 (just your case) called `live-restore`.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/live-restore/#enable-the-live-restore-option

> Starting with Docker Engine 1.12, you can configure the daemon so that containers remain running if the daemon becomes unavailable. The live restore option helps reduce container downtime due to daemon crashes, planned outages, or upgrades.

To enable it, update the `daemon.json` with this.

```
{
"live-restore": true
}
```

Then you just send a `SIGHUP` to the docker engine.

Make sure to do all necessary backups, just in case.

Comment: How do I safely send that signal and how do I know if it took the new config?

Comment: You can do a `kill -HUP <pid of docker daemon>`, to check if the new config is used, do a `lsof <pid of docker daemon>` and check that the correct config file is listed.